# How to get a RichTextBox to dock properly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi the problem I have is that I cant get the RichTextBox to fill the full panel. I've tried using a dockPanel but it does not seem to do the job.
The code is also included below. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
P.S this is using Modern UI as the template.

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="Modern_UI_Test.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                  Title = "Packet Sniffer" 
                  LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z"
                  Style="{StaticResource BlankWindow}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" >
                    <DockPanel Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel1" Width="Auto" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="Auto" />
                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Name="textBox2" Width="Auto" />
                        <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Label>
                <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                  Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" >
                    <RichTextBox Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

Comment: What exactly is it doing/what do you expect? The way I read that code, the `RichTextBox` should fill a `Label` tag which would *maybe* fill the second column of the grid, which is in a dock panel (useless from what I can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in `Label` Tag, substitute it with `GroupBox`.
remove Label.